# Linux - awk selection

Tags: linux, awk

I am new to Linux and for a program I'm currently working on I need to preprocess some .txt data. Let's say I have a .txt file with some data analysis. Each analysis has two lines - one with date information and second with obtained data. For example

```
Date: 19:00
Result: 19845
Date: 19:01
Result: 1875
Date: 19:02
Result: 19545
Date: 19:03
Result: 14595
...
```

and so on.

I would like to write a script that would take each third analysis and save it into another file. I assume that awk could do it, but I searched and somehow I ended only with script that selects each third line, but not each third analysis. Can please anybody push me forward a little bit? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You should add the script that you've got at the moment to your question.

Comment: Also, you should define what you mean by *each third analysis*. Is it the number in the line, or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think your question has more chances to get answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hello, by third analysis I mean each third Date line and each third Result line. My current script is: cat result.txt | awk 'NR%3==1' > result2.txt

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
awk '/Result/{r++;if(r%3==0)print}' yourfile
```

Every time you see the word "Result", increment r. Print if r mod 3 is zero.

Or if you want the date too, you can save that every time it goes by like this:

```
awk '/Date/{date=$0} /Result/{r++;if(r%3==0)print date,$0}' yourfile
```

Comment: Or, to do both lines (as seems to be required): `awk '/Result/{r++;if(r%3==0)print} /Date/{d++;if(d%3==0)print}'`.  Sometimes, brute force is sufficient.  It does assume the data file is properly laid out — no occurrences of two dates or two results in a row.

Comment: Thank you all for your effort, both answers helped!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
awk '
    NR%2 == 1 {date = $0} 
    NR%2 == 0 {analysis = date ORS $0} 
    NR%6 == 0 {print analysis}
' filename > outputfile
```

Comment: I really thank you. This helped me to understand what I needed to do. Code long and prosper!

Comment: Thanks @user3349015. Welcome to SO. Please read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to see what's expected of someone asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!(NR%6){print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}' file
Date: 19:02
Result: 19545
```